# DataTables getting the error TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#progresstable').DataTable')

Tags: javascript, ruby, datatables

When table is rendered firs time I am getting this error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#progresstable').DataTable')

When I click refresh the table is rendered properly.
Don't know how to fix it, it is consistent for all my tables and seems to be based on an additional info, The Safari console indicates the error happening for line 9 in this file which is script from datatables.net:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
```

Below is the entire code:

```
    <!-- DataTables css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <!-- DataTables js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTables jQuery UI -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTables tableTools -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/css/dataTables.tableTools.min.css">

    <% provide(:title, 'TBMs Daily Progress') %>

    <% if signed_in? %>

        <h3>TBMs Max Station by day - Today's date: <%=@current_date%><%=" - Records: "%><%=@count%></h3>

      <% if @tbms_progress_W.present? %>
          <% if @current_date != @tbms_progress_W.daily_date %>
            <h6 class="error-message">
                <%= "Today's location for TBM W is not loaded" %>
                <%= " Last TBM W recorded date was: " %>
                <%=@tbms_progress_W.daily_date %>
            </h6>
          <% else %> 
            <%= "" %>
          <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <div class="pull-left"> <%= "TBM W location unknown" %> </div>
        <% end %>

      <% if @tbms_progress_E.present? %>
          <% if @current_date != @tbms_progress_E.daily_date %>
              <h6 class="error-message">
                  <%= "Today's location for TBM E is not loaded" %>
                  <%= " Last TBM E recorded date was: " %>
                  <%=@tbms_progress_E.daily_date %>
              </h6>
          <% else %> 
            <%= "" %>
          <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <div class="pull-right"> <%= "TBM E location unknown" %> </div>
        <% end %>
        </br>

        <div>
            <div class="pull-left">
                <% if current_user.admin? %>
                    <%= link_to "Add new location", new_tbms_progress_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %>
                <% end %>
                <%= link_to "List view", tbms_progresses_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
                <%= link_to "Current Location", currentlocation_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
                <%= link_to "Daily Stats", tbms_stats_table_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
            </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <%= "Today's: " %>
            <%= link_to "Schedule", scheduletable_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
          <%= link_to "Readings List", all_readings_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
        </div>
        </div>
        </br></br>

        <table id="progresstable" class="display cell-border compact hover order-column row-border stripe">
            <thead style="background-color: Gainsboro;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Daily Date</th>
                    <th>TBM ID</th>
                    <th>Max Station</th>
                    <th>TBM Status</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% @tbms_progresses.each do |tbms_progress| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= tbms_progress.daily_date %></td>
                        <td><%= tbms_progress.tbm_id %></td>
                        <td><%= number_with_precision tbms_progress.max_station, precision: 2 %></td>
                        <td><%= tbms_progress.tbm_status %></td>
                        <td><%= link_to tbms_progress.id, tbms_progress %></td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot style="background-color: Gainsboro;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Daily Date</th>
                    <th>TBM ID</th>
                    <th>Max Station</th>
                    <th>TBM Status</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

        <h6>Legend: W aka TBM1 or 26900, E aka TBM2 or 27000</h6>

    <% else %>
        <%= render 'instruments/unsigned' %>
    <% end %>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#progresstable tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $('#progresstable thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+'" />' );
        } );

         var table = $('#progresstable').DataTable({
              "pagingType": "full_numbers",
              "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]],
              "dom": '<"top"fl>rt<"bottom"ip>T<"clear">',
          "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
              "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "print",
                {
                "sExtends":    "collection",
                "sButtonText": "Save",
                            "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                }
            ]
          },
            bJQueryUI: true,
            aaSorting: [ [0,"desc"], [1, "desc"] ],
            bDeferRender: true,
            bStateSave: true
        });

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
            $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                table
                    .column( colIdx )
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            } );
        } );
      } );
    </script>
```

Comment: This seems to have a lot less to do with Ruby and a lot more to do with JavaScript.  Maybe dispense with the server-side code and just show the client-side code so it's easier to follow?

Comment: Also, switch out the minified version of the JS library for the non-minified version so it is easier to see what's causing the error

Comment: switched to non-minified, I got the exact same error. The error is the same in development and production.

Comment: minified or non-minified, the line 9 pointed in the console is: <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jquery-ui/core.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: put all links refs to css and js in application.html.erb, after turbolinks and good by errors. Seems that browsers need to cache all of this before page x in the app is due for render.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the dependecies are:

```
1. <!-- DataTables CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

Then write your code and after it add

```
2.  <!-- DataTables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Note: The versions can variate